# Trouble building project composer package requires ext-sodium - missing on build server

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I am suddenly getting an error when trying to run build job on AWS.
Using Ubuntu standard:5.0 for building the project.

Its the sodium extension that is missing.

Would love some help on what to do to get this running again..

Output from the build log:

```
[Container] 2023/07/17 12:55:43 Running command composer install
Download composer.phar ...
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...

Composer (version 2.5.8) successfully installed to: /tmp/composer.phar
Use it: php /tmp/composer.phar

Move composer.phar to /root/.phpenv/versions/8.0.28/composer
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update.

  Problem 1
    - lcobucci/jwt is locked to version 4.1.5 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - lcobucci/jwt 4.1.5 requires ext-sodium * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's sodium extension.
  Problem 2
    - lcobucci/jwt 4.1.5 requires ext-sodium * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's sodium extension.
    - league/oauth2-server 8.3.3 requires lcobucci/jwt ^3.4.6 || ^4.0.4 -> satisfiable by lcobucci/jwt[4.1.5].
    - league/oauth2-server is locked to version 8.3.3 and an update of this package was not requested.

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /root/.phpenv/versions/8.0.28/etc/php.ini
    - /root/.phpenv/versions/8.0.28/etc/conf.d/memory.ini
    - /root/.phpenv/versions/8.0.28/etc/conf.d/xdebug.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-sodium` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.

[Container] 2023/07/17 12:55:47 Command did not exit successfully composer install exit status 2
[Container] 2023/07/17 12:55:47 Phase complete: INSTALL State: FAILED
[Container] 2023/07/17 12:55:47 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: composer install. Reason: exit status 2
```

Build spec:

```
phases:
  install:
    commands:
       - echo $AUTH > auth.json
       - composer install
       - yarn install
       - yarn run prod
```

Error occurs when trying to run composer install.

Kind regards
Ole

Comment: From the error message: _"Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-sodium` to temporarily ignore these required extensions."_ Option or not?